# Google Cloud DNS invalidZoneApex while trying to delete NS and SOA

Tags: google-cloud-dns

Using the [DNS API](https://cloud.google.com/dns/api/v1/) I am trying to delete the `NS` and `SOA` record but I am getting this message:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalidZoneApex",
    "message": "The resource record set 'entity.change.deletions[0]' is invalid because a zone must contain exactly one resource record set of type 'SOA' at the apex."
   },
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalidZoneApex",
    "message": "The resource record set 'entity.change.deletions[1]' is invalid because a zone must contain exactly one resource record set of type 'NS' at the apex."
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "The resource record set 'entity.change.deletions[0]' is invalid because a zone must contain exactly one resource record set of type 'SOA' at the apex."
 }
}
```

Via the google web console, I can update/modify the records and this helps me to add my custom `NS` and `SOA` so that I can use my own **vanity** name.

Besides that if I want to add a new `NS` or `SOA` I get an **alreadyexists** error.

How could totally manipulate the zone via the DNS API?

Answer (score 1):

You can't delete the NS and SOA records because they are system-managed and required by the specifications for DNS - the error message says essentially this. You can't add a new one because you can only have one RRSet of a particular type at a particular name.

In general you can *replace* record sets by deleting and re-adding them in the same transaction. Which is to say, having a `deletions` and an `additions` in the same [Changes.create](https://cloud.google.com/dns/api/v1/changes/create#http-request) call. I'm not sure offhand whether you can do this for the NS and SOA types at will, but if it works in the Cloud Console it will work on the API as the console just makes normal API calls.